# Why does my async function that returns a Future<int> stall at await for each?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My goal with this function is to return an integer representing all of the habits completed by the user. My databases structure is a collection of habits, each with a sub-collection containing its history. The function below utilizes a list of habits, and using the habit's ID it gets a stream of the history for that habit. My problem is that when I try to loop through the history for each habit it stalls at the `await for`. Any advice would be appreciated, I am still trying to fully understand streams/asynchronous functions.

```
Future<int> getCompleteHabits(User user, List<Habit> habits) async {
  int completed = 0;
  if(habits.isNotEmpty) {
    for(Habit habit in habits) {
      Stream<List<HabitHistory>> streamHistory = db.streamHabitHistory(user, habit.id);
      await for(var h in streamHistory){
        print(habit.title);
        print(h);
      }
      print("test");
    }
  }
  return completed;
}
```

This function will add to the variable completed, however, since I cannot access all the history I have yet to do so.

This function prints the following to the console, it doesn't get to the `print("test")`.

> flutter: Get in bed by 11:30 pm
>
> flutter: [Instance of 'HabitHistory', Instance of 'HabitHistory', Instance of 'HabitHistory', Instance of 'HabitHistory', Instance of 'HabitHistory']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abion47 stated the stream has not been closed so the await for is never complete. It is waiting for new events.

Knowing this I can use the `await streamHabitHistory(user, habit.id).first` to get the list (so it is not waiting for events). The code is below.

```
Future<int> getCompleteHabits(User user, List<Habit> habits) async {
  int completed = 0;
  if(habits.isNotEmpty) {
    for(Habit habit in habits) {
      List<HabitHistory> history = await db.streamHabitHistory(user, habit.id).first;
      for (HabitHistory h in history) {
        completed = completed + h.completed.length;
      }

    }
  }
  return completed;
}
```

Comment: `first` on a stream returns a `Future`. Since you are already in an `async` method, the `then` can be removed; simply awaiting `first` will get you the list. (I don't recommend mixing `then` and `await` as it can make the code confusing to follow.)

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense, I am going to update the answer now. I now get the list using `await db.streamHabitHistory(user, habit.id).first;` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentaion on Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams):

> Streams are done when there are no more events in them, and the code receiving the events is notified of this just as it is notified that a new event arrives. When reading events using an **await for** loop, the loops stops when the stream is done.

The reason your loop is hanging is that the stream hasn't yet been closed. It will continue to hang until the stream gets closed or until you execute a `break` or `return` statement within the loop.

Comment: Wow ok this makes sense, when you say close is that the same as dispose? If it was disposed would it then know that the stream is done? I also just moments ago figured out a way around it so I am going to add that as an answer as well.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know what you think.

Comment: @AnthonySette You can't "close" a stream in the typical way. The way a stream gets closed is when its controller fires a "done" event. Judging from the [implementation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html), the firestore package never bothers to do this, instead just letting the stream get garbage collected once its listeners have unsubscribed. This makes a certain amount of sense, as the streams in the firestore package are designed for getting realtime updates when the services they are attached to receive changes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and that's true because when changes are made to a specific portion of the users database the parts of the app that are listening to a corresponding stream are updated. Thank you so much!